# Debian - Using TFTP in a bash script

Tags: bash, debian, scripting, tftp

I'm actually using RPiTC (Raspberry Pi Thin Client).

I had create a script to see if my Hostname has the same name than a file.
And now I want to say "If my Hostname don't have the same name than my file, then take the file with tftp protocol".

My tftp server is on my windows xp. So I want to do this:

```
Hostname is different from the file name
                |
                |------> Use tftp Protocol to take the file on my windows.
```

This is my script actually:

```
do_start()
#Creating and checking my Hostname variable
ThisHost=$(hostname)
date=$(date)
echo "This is my hostname check:
echo $ThisHost

#This will find the file in the /home/rpitc folder and save it to a variable:
dest=$(find /home/rpitc/ -name "$ThisHost.ica")
echo "This is my dest check:"
echo $dest
findfile="${dest##*/}"
echo "This is my findfile check with extension:"
echo $findfile
echo "This is my findfile check WITHOUT extension:"
echo "${findfile%.*}"

#If check to see if my hostname $ThisHost matches the file $findfile:
if test "$ThisHost" = "${findfile%.*}"

then
    echo "Worked!"
    echo $ThisHost "is correct. Connected the" $date >> /home/rpitc/skelog
    exit 0
else
tftp=$(tftp 10.1.0.203)
GetIt=$("\Test\$ThisHost.ica")
    echo "My tftp test:"
    echo $tftp
    echo "My GetIt test:"
    echo $GetIt
    echo $ThisHost "is not correct, update of the file at" $date >> /home/rpitc/skelog
    exit 0
fi
```

So I need ideas for this part of my script:

```
else
tftp=$(tftp 10.1.0.203)
GetIt=$("\Test\$ThisHost.ica")
    echo "My tftp test:"
    echo $tftp
    echo "My GetIt test:"
    echo $GetIt
    echo $ThisHost "is not correct, update of the file at" $date >> /home/rpitc/skelog
    exit 0
fi
```

I don't know how to use the tftp protocol in my bash script...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `here documents`.

```
tftp 10.1.0.203 << fin
   get /test/${ThisHost}.ica
   quit
fin
```

That should get `/test/${ThisHost}.ica` from your tftp server.