# Check exist file on another pc

Tags: bash, scripting, find, tftp

Yesterday I had ask how to use my tftp protocol in my bash script:
[Debian - Using TFTP in a bash script](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/180429/debian-using-tftp-in-a-bash-script)

And now I have a problem with my tftp protocol.
The file who was taken depend of my Hostname.
So if I put a wrong Hostname, my tftp protocol don't say "Hey the file doesn't exist!". He just create an empty file...

So it's possible to check if the file exist on my tftp server.
Something like this:

```
find 10.1.0.203 /test/${ThisHost}.ica
```

I know this line is not working it's just an example.

I want to do something like this in my script:

```
else
ThisHost=$(hostname)
if
find 10.1.0.203 /test/${ThisHost}.ica
then
tftp 10.1.0.203 << fin
get /test/${ThisHost}.ica
quit
fin
exec iceweasel /home/rpitc/${ThisHost}.ica
else
zenity --error --text="Your Hostname is wrong."
fi
fi
```

So it's just an example.
But if you know how to do that (with real commands), that's would be nice!

Comment: Are you saying your TFTP server creates an empty file when you try to **get** a non-existent file or when you try to **put** one? The former would surprise me and sounds wrong.

Comment: It's when I try to get.

Comment: I see. That's a very weird TFTP server. In that case there is no way to test if the file exists without creating it as a side effect because TFTP doesn't have an enumeration capability.

Comment: My server (tftpd-hpa) has the same behaviour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to tftp's help you can't:

```
tftp> ?
Commands may be abbreviated.  Commands are:

connect         connect to remote tftp
mode            set file transfer mode
put             send file
get             receive file
quit            exit tftp
verbose         toggle verbose mode
trace           toggle packet tracing
status          show current status
binary          set mode to octet
ascii           set mode to netascii
rexmt           set per-packet retransmission timeout
timeout         set total retransmission timeout
?               print help information
```

neither you can make a simple `ls` and see what files you have. TFTP (Trivial FTP) is a very reduced one, so if you need to check files you will have to switch to an ftp server.

Comment: Yes I know it's not possible with the tftp protocol. But maybe it's possible to check this with a bash command no?

Comment: Yes, you can just check if the created file has zero size (in case it has any content), or if you own the tftp server create the files with a content inside. Just a simpe OK or something like that will do. After you get the file from the tftp server you can `cat` the file and check if it hast the OK insido or not thus knowing if the get has succeeded or not.

Comment: How can I see if the file has zero size? I'm not very good in bash. And Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @Aragmond `[ -s filename ]` succeeds if the file has non-zero size.